# Printing different colored text with hex color constants in do-loop

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

Following is a program I was trying to print a Text with Ten different colors but since there is no dectohex(4) function in Intel fortran how could it be implemented for desired output on a quickwin app.

Thanks

```
 ! build as a QuickWin App.
USE IFQWIN
INTEGER(2) result
INTEGER(4) i
TYPE (xycoord) xys

result = INITIALIZEFONTS()
result = SETFONT('t''Arial''h18w10pvib')

CALL MOVETO(INT2(100),INT2(100),xys)
grstat=SETCOLORRGB(#0000FF) !red color
CALL OUTGTEXT('The brown fix jumps over lazy dog. ')
!Now print ten times with different colors

do i=1,10
        grstat=SETCOLORRGB(dectohex(i))
       CALL OUTGTEXT('The brown fix jumps over lazy dog. ')
end do

END
```

Comment: You need to say what the ten different colors you want are. Just converting int 1 though int 10 to hex won't accomplish what you want (that would yield successively lighter dark reds). Once you know the ten colors, you could just make an array of the ten color values and then loop through that.

Comment: It is not predefined colors. It could be red, green, yellow, without shades. I tried using SETCOLOR(INT2(4))  and it is not producing color output. Basically reference manual encourages use of SETCOLORRGB. You are saying rightly. It colors colud be wrapped in an enumerated type variable and iterate through this could you present an example.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hatsoff to you! I found the solution as per Scott Johnson first comment.

What I did is made an integer array of 4 bytes to replicate 'enum' data type which is not avalable in fortran by default.

```
INTEGER(4) , DIMENSION (3)::COLORS
COLORS=(/#0000FF, #00FF00, #FF0000/) !just 3 colors to illustrate the solution
do i=1,3
        grstat=SETCOLORRGB(COLORS(i))
      CALL OUTGTEXT('The brown fix jumps over lazy dog. ')
end do
```

You can extend this concept for other programs.
Thank.

Jai Imran Khan.